# Text Block with FontStretch is inheriting FontStyle and Weight

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF control which contains a number of toggle buttons for setting font weight, style, decoration and stretch. In each toggle button there is TextBlock which shows the style.

For some reason the toggle button I have created for Condensed FontStretch, **at runtime** appears in ExtraBold, Oblique and condensed. Equally any text set to Condensed also appears this way. In the desinger the button appears correct.

I think it might be because I set other buttons with the same font family to ExtraBold and Oblique and the fonts is getting saved in the cache.

```
<ToggleButton Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,232,0,0" Name="boldButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36">
        <TextBlock Text="Abc" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,232,0,0" Name="extraBoldButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36">
        <TextBlock Text="Abc" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton  Content="Abc"  FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,261,0,0" Name="italicButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
    <ToggleButton  Content="Abc"  FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Oblique" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,261,91,0" Name="obliqueButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
```

Comment: You might override the Font properties in the code behind.

Comment: No, removed all font styleing etc from the XAML and set it in the code. No effect. I've even tried restarting VS and deleting the font cache file. Thanks

Comment: Intrestingly when the program is run on another machine the condensed button text appears normal (not condensed, not italic or not bold).

Comment: If it shows fine on another machine I'd ask are you building to a browser instead of out-of-browser? If so, clear you cache. ;)

Comment: Well its not exactly fine, its not condensed as it should be, so it does seem to be a cache problem. I have deleted the presentation foundation cache but that had no effect.